# Trying to authenticate users against the AD - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, ldap

A web application where people can view their SSRS reports internally or externally.

I'm trying to authenticate users logging in against the active directory groups using custom authorize roles, so the reports can be secured down based on if they are in a particular AD Group or not.

Now I know this works out the box with windows auth/form auth, but I'm using a custom authentication due to other reasons but what I do have is a table which has the custom usernames that the users are logging with mapped against their windows credentials.

I've been following this [blog](http://www.benramey.com/2014/10/20/active-directory-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc-5-with-forms-authentication-and-group-based-authorization/) to test out this method of authenticating against the active directory groups and customized it to pass in the windows credentials mapped to the custom user login but having no luck so far.

With regards to the custom authentication, when I go find the matching domain name out of my table and store that domain name into the session variable, which then is passed into this AD authentication process for checking if the user exists in the group or not, see code below.

Custom authorize attribute,

```
using Helpers;
using Models;
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Application.Validators
{
public class AuthorizeADAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string Group { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Group))
            {
                return true;
            }

            var logOnInfo = httpContext.Session["LogOnInfo"] as LogOnModel;
            var username = logOnInfo.DomainName;

            try
            {
                return LDAPHelper.UserIsMemberOfGroups(username, Group);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
    }
}
}
```

LDAP Helper,

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Web;

namespace Application.Helpers
{
public  class LDAPHelper 
{
    public static string GetLDAPContainer()
    {
        Uri ldapUri;
        ParseLDAPConnectionString(out ldapUri);
        return HttpUtility.UrlDecode(ldapUri.PathAndQuery.TrimStart('/'));
    }

    public static bool ParseLDAPConnectionString(out Uri ldapUri)
    {
        string connString = 
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ADConnectionString"]
   .ConnectionString;
        return Uri.TryCreate(connString, UriKind.Relative, out ldapUri);
    }
    public static bool UserIsMemberOfGroups(string username, string Group)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Group))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Verify that the user is in the given AD group (if any)   
        using (var context = BuildPrincipalContext())
        {
            var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context,
            IdentityType.SamAccountName,
            username); 

            return userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(context, IdentityType.Name, Group);
        }
    }

    public static PrincipalContext BuildPrincipalContext()
    {
        string container = GetLDAPContainer();
        return new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null, container);
    }
}
}
```

LDAP Connection string in the web.config (can confirm is correct),

```
 <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://CN=Managers;OU=Groups,OU=Users,DC=domain"/>
```

My issue I think is when I'm trying to return the container (GetLDAPHelper Method) from the LDAP conn string back to the PrincipalContext it justs returning null and throwing an error.

I'm looking to see if anyone has done anything remotely similar or is there a more suitable method for trying to achieve what i'm doing?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Null reference exception when my GetLDAPContainer method goes to the ParseLDAPConnectionString method to return the ldapUri.

when I'm debugging and put the cursor over the connString variable it shows me the connection string correctly, just doesn't return it to the GetLDAPContainer method.

Comment: ldapUri.PathAndQuery is null that's why.

Comment: I understand this and this is where I'm stuck as I can't understand why

Comment: You're passing the domain name as the username parameter. Are you sure? var username = logOnInfo.DomainName;

Comment: Yeah, this is the user's windows credentials that are mapped to their custom username login and I'm trying to compare that DomainName against the domain name in the AD Group.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the LDAP connection string is not a valid `Uri`, so when you attempt to make it one, `ldapUri` remains null. If you need to parse the connection string, for some reason, you'll need to do it another way. You can't use `Uri`.