# ASP.NET MVC - Active Directory authentication for custom login process

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

So I'm developing a web application that allows users to view their SQL reporting services reports externally, and users log in with a custom username the user created themselves.

I would like to authenticate these usernames against their windows domain accounts, which a check against the active directory to see if the user is in a relevant group and that will determine the access rights to certain reports.

Now I can't use windows authentication as a login procedure to my web application but I do have a SQL table which stores their custom username (which they log in with) mapped against their windows domain account, and on login I store the domain name into the session (stores the windows account credentials as a string) as a property which is exposed by my base controller.

I've already gone off and tried this solution,

http://www.benramey.com/2014/10/20/active-directory-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc-5-with-forms-authentication-and-group-based-authorization/

but as you can see from my previous post (see here [Trying to authenticate users against the AD - ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43847720/trying-to-authenticate-users-against-the-ad-asp-net-mvc/43848768#43848768)) i'm not getting the desired result.

Just looking for some advice on how I can achieve authenticating against the AD with my scenario.

Comment: You say you are using custom authentication. Are you overriding the SSRS authentication and authorization routines?

Comment: Yes, I use the table that I mentioned to also pass in the windows account to the reports, but I want to secure down other factors such as navigation links based on AD authentication.

If you look into at the blog i mentioned, you'll see they use custom authorise attributes that you pass a group as an attribute to the authorise attribute, I'm looking for something along that lines.